# The output from if/elif is not coming up in my code for python

Tags: python

```
rent = int("300")
shopping = int("150")
clothes = int("200")
print("you have ", + cash, "dollars")
print("You have 3 options to spend your money")
print("$300 - Rent - 1")
print("$150 - Shopping - 2")
print("$200 - Clothes - 3")
choice = input("Enter a number between 1-3 to choose how you spend your money")

if choice == 1:
    print("you now have", cash - rent, "dollars")
elif choice == 2:
    print("you now have", cash - shopping, "dollars")
```

the if/elif part will not print the stuff included inside of it.

Comment: That's because `choice` is neither equal to 1 nor to 2.

Comment: choice = int(input())

Comment: the int(input()) one did not work

Answer (score 1):

The return value of `input` is a string, which cannot equal a number. Change your conditions to `choice == "1"` and `choice == "2"`.

You should also include `.strip()` after your call to `input` just in case the user enters extra whitespace before or after the number. And remember to include an `else` block to handle the case that they enter something else.

Comment: i did choice == "1","2" and it did nothing